# How do record updates behave internally?

Tags: haskell

```
data Thing = Thing {a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int, (...) , z :: Int} deriving Show

foo = Thing 1 2 3 4 5 (...) 26
mkBar x = x { c = 30 }

main = do print $ mkBar foo
```

What is copied over when I mutate foo in this way? As opposed to mutating part of a structure directly.

```
Data Thing = Thing {a :: IORef Int, b :: IORef Int, (...) , z :: IORef Int}
instance Show Thing where
(...something something unsafePerformIO...)

mkFoo = do a <- newIORef 1
           (...)
           z <- newIORef 26
           return Thing a b (...) z
mkBar x = writeIORef (c x) 30

main = do foo <- mkFoo
          mkBar foo
          print foo
```

Does compiling with optimizations change this behavior?

Comment: Something, something, something, `unsafePerformIO`. Something, something, something, complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, the pointers to the unchanged `Int` components are copied (and the constructor tag, if you wish to say so). It doesn't make much difference whether an `Int` or a pointer to one is copied, but if the components were large structures, it would.

Since the fields are not strict, the behaviour is, afaik, independent of optimisation. If the fields were strict, with optimisations, they might be unpacked into the constructor and then the raw `Int#` values would be copied.

In the second example, nothing is copied, the contents of the `IORef` are overwritten.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Daniel's answer, you can think of

```
data Foo = Foo {a::Int, b::Int}
update foo x = foo{a=x}
```

as just about the same as

```
data Foo = Foo Int Int
update (Foo a b) x = Foo x b
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the case that updating a field results in copying the whole structure.  But if the compiler can prove that the structure is used in a single threaded way it can do update in place.  I don't know of any implementation that does this, but you could imagine doing it with single bit reference counts.

Comment: I think Clean does it as single-threadedness is built into its type system. Clean is not a Haskell implementation though.

Comment: Yes, Clean has uniqueness types which allows them to use destructive update of e.g. arrays.